# SharePoint IIS/ URL errors

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis7, 401, 403

This issue started when we were going to reroute our main site (web app) to a new domain. It didn't on my end so I tried to pull it back - recalling and extending the header, changing bindings, checking permissions, everything but here is where I am now.

I cannot access main web app and the error according to the IIS log is

```
  ModuleName SPRequestModule
  Notification RESOLVE_REQUEST_CACHE 
  HttpStatus 403  HttpReason Forbidden  HttpSubStatus 0  ErrorCode The
  operation completed successfully.  (0x0)
```

I cannot access Central Admin outside of the server on which it is hosted (from the Central Admin link) and the error according to the IIS log is

```
ModuleName WindowsAuthenticationModule 
Notification AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST 
HttpStatus 401 
HttpReason Unauthorized 
HttpSubStatus 1 
ErrorCode No credentials are available in the security package
```

I can't even delete the web apps to start over, because I get

```
ModuleName ManagedPipelineHandler 
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
HttpStatus 403 
HttpReason Forbidden 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0)
```

I want to set the whole thing on fire. Here is what I have eliminated - it is not SQL and it is not permissions, I have opened up permissions wide and still getting the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update, central admin is back after stopping and starting w3svc. Now my issues are the 403/ 401 for the webapp.

Comment: can you elaborate on "This issue started when we were going to reroute our main site (web app) to a new domain. It didn't on my end so I tried to pull it back". So what you have done to reroute?. Have you extended the web application through Central Admin with new host header or you have made changes manually in IIS?

Comment: Sure! I deleted the header and reextended it. Here is where I think I went wrong, because the new url still wasn't working. As far as I knew I had the bindings right and the alternate access mappings, but nothing seemed to get it route to the new url. I tried to make everything as it was, and that was when I started to get the 443 error. Does that help?

Comment: I had similar situation on one slow environment, I was extending things didn't work so I deleted, where in fact extended web app wasn't provisioned on all servers. I end up redoing everything and waiting bit more between the steps and ensuring everything was provisioned on all front ends.

Comment: I did indeed have to delete and start over, it just became a mess. Thanks for help!